# Scrapy: How to use init_request and start_requests together?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I need to make an initial call to a service before I start my scraper (the initial call, gives me some cookies and headers), I decided to use InitSpider and override the `init_request` method to achieve this. however I also need to use `start_requests` to build my links and add some meta values like proxies and whatnot to that specific spider, but I'm facing a problem. whenever I override `start_requests`, my crawler doesn't call `init_request` anymore and I can not do the initialization and in order to get init_request working is to not override the `start_requests` method which is impossible in my case. any suggestions or possible solutions to my code:

```
class SomethingSpider(InitSpider):
name = 'something'
allowed_domains = ['something.something']

aod_url = "https://something?="


start_urls = ["id1","id2","id3"]

custom_settings = {
    'DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS' : False,
    'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 20,
    'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 10,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 3,
    'COOKIES_ENABLED': True,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 20
}

def init_request(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(url="https://something",callback=self.check_temp_cookie, meta={'proxy': 'someproxy:1111'})


def check_temp_cookie(self, response):
    """Check the response returned by a login request to see if we are
    successfully logged in.
    """
    if response.status == 200:
        print("H2")
        # Now the crawling can begin..
        return self.initialized()
    else:
        print("H3")
        # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.


def start_requests(self):
    print("H4")
    proxies = ["xyz:0000","abc:1111"]
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.aod_url+url, callback=self.parse, meta={'proxy': random.choice(proxies)})



def parse(self, response):
            #some processing happens

            yield {
            #some data
            }

        except Exception as err:
            print("Connecting to...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spiders page (generic spiders section) on [official scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.5/topics/spiders.html#generic-spiders) doesn't have any mention of `InitSpider` You are trying to use.

`InitSpider` class from https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.5.0/scrapy/spiders/init.py written ~10 years ago (at that... ancient versions of scrapy `start_requests` method worked completely differently).

From this perspective I recommend You to not use undocumented and probably outdated `InitSpider`.

On current versions of scrapy required functionality can be implemented using regular `Spider` class:

```python
import scrapy

class SomethingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
...
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://something",callback=self.check_temp_cookie, meta={'proxy': 'someproxy:1111'})

    def check_temp_cookie(self, response):
    """Check the response returned by a login request to see if we are
    successfully logged in.
    """
        if response.status == 200:
            print("H2")
            # Now the crawling can begin..
            ...
            #Schedule next requests here:
            for url in self.start_urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=self.aod_url+url, callback=self.parse, ....})
        else:
            print("H3")
            # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking speicfically at incorporating logging in then I would reccomend you look at [Using FormRequest.from_response() to simulate a user login](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin) in the scrapy docs.

Here is the spider example they give:

```
import scrapy

def authentication_failed(response):
    # TODO: Check the contents of the response and return True if it failed
    # or False if it succeeded.
    pass

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        if authentication_failed(response):
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return

        # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

finally, you can have a look at how too add proxies to your scrapy middleware as per this example (zyte are the guys who wrote scrapy) ["How to set up a custom proxy in Scrapy?"](https://www.zyte.com/blog/scrapy-proxy/)